# Display a custom field of current taxonomy on taxonomy page

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

I have a custom taxonomy called Books with 2 custom taxonomy fields. One is called book_tagline and other called book_short_desc

So for example If I have a Books Category like School Books and the 2 custom fields contains values as

book_tagline = 12th grade all school books
book_short_desc = we have all 12th grade school books...

On the Books Category page I would like to display the above 2 custom fields

Here is my code but its not displaying the values

```
$termcat = get_term_by( 'slug', get_query_var('term'), get_query_var('taxonomy') );
$icat_id = $termcat->term_id;
$icat_tag = get_term_meta($icat_id, '_pc_ccat_tagline');
 $icat_desc = get_term_meta($icat_id, '_pc_ccat_desc');
```

The above code is not inside a loop. But the code is in the taxonomy-books template page

Thanks

Comment: Are you getting term id?

Comment: Yes I am able display term_id, term name and term description just not the custom fields. Instead of displaying the values it just displays the word ARRAY. Thanks

Comment: Check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code

```
$pc_ccat_tagline = get_term_meta( get_queried_object_id(), '_pc_ccat_tagline', true);

$pc_ccat_desc = get_term_meta( get_queried_object_id(), '_pc_ccat_desc', true);
```

Do not forget to do echo.

If this code does not work than just pass true in your code

```
$icat_desc = get_term_meta($icat_id, '_pc_ccat_desc',true);
```

Comment: Brilliant the first code worked. I never knew that I had to use true. what does true do? Thanks again

Comment: True will give you the value and without true it is taking false as a default one and false will always return an array.  If you do not wish to pass true than you can have the value by doing even for an instance : echo $icat_desc[0];